# Dual of Unbounded Linear Program

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

For an LP of the form
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{\textbf{x}}{\text{minimize}}
& & \textbf{c}^T \textbf{x} \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \textbf{A} \textbf{x} \geq \textbf{b} \\
& && \textbf{x} \geq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
the dual is 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{\textbf{y}}{\text{maximize}}
& & \textbf{y}^T \textbf{b} \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \textbf{y}^T \textbf{A} \leq \textbf{c}^T \\
& && \textbf{y} \geq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
My question is, what is the dual if we remove the $\textbf{x} \geq 0$ constraint from the primal problem? In other words, what is the dual of 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{\textbf{x}}{\text{minimize}}
& & \textbf{c}^T \textbf{x} \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \textbf{A} \textbf{x} \geq \textbf{b}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the table below and see how to transform a primal problem into a dual problem. You have a $\color{blue}{\texttt{Min}}$-problem. Therefore you read the table from right to left. In your case you go to the 6 th row. Here you can  read, if the primal Min-problem has free variables the corresponding constraints are equalities.

Consequently the dual of your second problem is

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{\textbf{y}}{\text{maximize}}
& & \textbf{y}^T \textbf{b} \\
& \text{subject to}
& & \textbf{y}^T \textbf{A} =\textbf{c}^T \\
& && \textbf{y} \geq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask, from what reference is the table that you posted? It seems to be quite thorough!

Comment: The table is in my lecture notes (in german) from the university. I don´t have a reference like a book. But I can guarantee that it works for all cases.

Comment: @callculus I have a problem on quadratic programming I've been working on for days. Once I get my Lagrangian no longer in terms of $x$, I can't figure out how to get the dual problem out of it. Can you please help? I have a 100 point bounty: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571031/need-help-setting-up-and-solving-dual-problem