# convert following primal to dual LP with null RHS

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I would like to convert the following primal to its dual

\begin{align}
& \max c^T x \\[6pt]
& \text{s.t. } Ax=0
\end{align}

Since $A_{(72,95)}$, I couldn't write all constraints and bounds. Some bounds are in the following form:

$lb<x_{n}<ub$ or in this form $x_{n}=b$ or unconstrained.

Noteworthy the presence of 'imbalanced' variables in $A$ such that some columns have a unique nonzero entry of value $-1$ (gap variables) .

What would be a general procedure to convert this type of LP to its dual?

Comment: The table at the link should answer all/the most of your questions. If anything is unclear feel free to ask. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175857/dual-of-unbounded-linear-program/2175917#2175917

Comment: Thanks @callculus, although I couldn't figure out the case where the RHS b=0, would that mean that the obj fun of the dual=0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This following algorithmic approach helped me solve my problem. http://slahaie.net/docs/lpdual.pdf